# Query ImportRange on Google Sheets breaks with extra parameter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I'm wondering why when I add an extra two parameters (one on each function) that I get an Array literal error. Below is the function that runs perfectly fine.

```
 ={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url", "INVENTORY!$A:$Z"), 
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col15,Col17,Col18,Col7,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col21 WHERE Col15 IS NOT NULL 
    AND Col15 < "&F1&" 
    AND Col19 <> 'Printed' 
    AND Col20 = 'Restock' 
  ORDER BY Col15 ASC", 1);
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url", "PREINVENTORY!$A:$Z"),
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col19 WHERE Col19 <> 'FBA' AND Col17 = 1 AND Col7 IS NULL",0)}
```

When I add an extra parameters the sheet breaks and I get the array literal error suggesting I has mismatched columns sizes.

```
    ={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url", "INVENTORY!$A:$Z"), 
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col15,Col17,Col18,Col7,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col21 WHERE Col15 IS NOT NULL 
    AND Col15 < "&F1&" 
    AND Col19 <> 'Printed' 
    AND Col20 = 'Restock'
    AND Col22 = 1
  ORDER BY Col15 ASC", 1);
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url", "PREINVENTORY!$A:$Z"),
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col19 WHERE Col19 <> 'FBA' AND Col17 = 1 AND Col7 IS NULL AND Col22 = 1",0)}
```

Comment: I did a quick test using your formula after creating sample sheets for `INVENTORY` & `PREINVENTORY` but I'm unable to get the error you've mentioned and it works just fine on my end. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help members in the community to be able to fully replicate the issue.

Comment: Use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) to provide sample data. You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: So one of the tabs I am using is taking data from an google extension called GorillaROI and don't know why that would cause a break in the sheet considering all was fine before even with that being implemented in.

Comment: Also an update, so if I pull in Col22 for each range then it allows for the filter... any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: did you run both importranges first as standalone to connect your sheets by allowing the access?

Comment: @player0 Yes all was works perfectly when they are ran individually. The data I'm working with is pretty big and is using the extension above mentioned constantly and breaks as it is tied to AMZ's API so not sure really what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably one of your qyeries results in `#N/A`. Try accounting for that with `IFNA` like this:

```
={
  IFNA(
    QUERY(
      IMPORTRANGE("url", "INVENTORY!$A:$Z"), 
      "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
              Col5, Col15, Col17, Col18,
              Col7, Col11, Col12, Col13,
              Col14, Col21
       WHERE     Col15 IS NOT NULL 
             AND Col15 < " & F1 & " 
             AND Col19 <> 'Printed' 
             AND Col20 = 'Restock'
             AND Col22 = 1
       ORDER BY Col15",
      1
    ),
    {"Query returned nothing", SPLIT(REPT(",", 12), ",",,)}
  );
  IFNA(
    QUERY(
      IMPORTRANGE("url", "PREINVENTORY!$A:$Z"),
      "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
              Col5, Col8, Col9, Col10,
              Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14,
              Col15, Col19
       WHERE     Col19 <> 'FBA'
             AND Col17 = 1
             AND Col7 IS NULL
             AND Col22 = 1",
      0
    ),
    {"Query returned nothing", SPLIT(REPT(",", 12), ",",,)}
  )
}
```